# sed add text around regex

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I would like to be able to go:

```
sed "s/^\(\w+\)$/leftside\1rightside/"
```

and have the group matched by `(\w+\)` appear in between 'leftside' and 'rightside'.

But it seems like I have to pipe it twice, one for the left of the text, another time for the right. If anyone knows a way to do it in one pass, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I can think of no reason why it wouldn't work the way you wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that you probably specify the wrong regex. In your case, text will be added in the end and beginning of the line **only** if it consists **only** of word characters (given that your version of `sed` supports the `\w` notation). Also you didn't escape the `+` which you should do if not using the `-r` option.

Try starting with `sed "s/^\(.*\)$/leftside\1rightside/"` or just `sed "s/.*/leftside&rightside/"` and working from that.

Comment: I've checked and \w is not supported - that has been the main problem. This version works: $ echo "FIC" | sed "s/^\([A-Z]*\)$/pre\1post/"
preFICpost
So now I imagine it's just a matter of writing the rest of the \w character class

Comment: @user1476674 `sed` has its own notation for character classes. Try `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `\w`. The classes are listed [here](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/l-sed2.xml) for example, if you scroll down a little. Also, if the question is resolved, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer.